# codeigniter insert data into database with enum field

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, enums

I'm having an issue when creating/inserting data into the db. Whenever I submit the form it returns an error using form_validation. It works with my previous database but now it doesn't. I doubt it's on the data type enum.

controller:

```
public function create_item() {
  $data = array(
   'checklist_id' => $this->input->post('checklist_id'),
   'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
   'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
   'type'  => $this->input->post('type'), //with enum type
   'section' => $this->input->post('section'),
   'order_no' => $this->input->post('order_no'),
   'status' => $this->input->post('status'), //with enum type
   'date_created' => $this->input->post('date_created')
   );

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('title','Item Title','trim|required|callback_alpha_dash_space');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('order_no','Item Order','trim|required');

  $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_dash_space', '%s appears to be invalid. Must contain only alphabets.');
  $this->form_validation->set_message('required', '%s field must not be empty. ');

  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', ' Error adding an item!');
    redirect($this->agent->referrer());
  } else {
      $result = $this->checklist_item_model->put_item($data);
        if (!$result == TRUE) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Item added successfuly!');
        redirect('checklist_item', 'refresh');
      }
    }
 }
```

view:

```
<select class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
  <option value="0">Incomplete</option>
  <option value="1">Complete</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can u explain more show your validation code

Comment: also please include the error you're getting

Comment: thanks for the quick response. look my edit above.

Comment: $this->session->set_flashdata('error', ' Error adding an item!'); this error. meaning the the data isn't inserted.

Comment: you are appying validaton just on two input fields .....

Comment: wat is error your getting as output

Comment: the error I get is the error I've set when validation run is false.

Answer (score 0):

do validation like this in your controller

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('title','ItemTitle','trim|required|callback_alpha_dash_space');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('order_no','Item Order','trim|required');

 $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_dash_space', '%s appears to be invalid. Must contain only alphabets.');
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', '%s field must not be empty. ');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
           // do something here 
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Item added successfuly!');
    redirect('checklist_item', 'refresh');
        }
```

and in your view show validation error easily you can trace the error field

```
<?php if(validation_errors()) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></div>
    <p class="text-center mb30"></p>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: sorry but it also returns false.